# verb + up, verb meaning modification

Tags: verbs

Please share your thoughts that you have as an English native speaker about how does the word "up" added to a verb to the right side modify meaning of the verb.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am interested in a general reply, not a verb+up for a verb given in particular. Thank you.

Comment: There isn't a general rule. There are many verb+up phrases, and they tend to be phrasal verbs with ideomatic meanings.